# Google Analytics SDK UserActivity cannot show custom metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The SDK reference

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

shows that custom dimensions are part of the result Activity, *but custom metrics are not mentioned*

I have a very simple problem, but cannot seem to find the answer anywhere:
**How can I get the google analytics data, event by event, including my custom metrics?**

Lets say given a client id

I have tried connecting the dataLayer variables through Tag Manager to Google Analytics in various ways and cannot find the custom metrics in detail (i.e. raw, event by event) anywhere in Analytics - Seems that only Analytics 360 allows it via BigQuery; but there must be a way using the SDK

Or is it just not possible?